# Selenium Web Driver DragAndDropToOffset in Chrome not working?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

```
 private static void DragAndDropToOffset(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement source, int xposOffset, int yposOffset)
    {
        Actions mouseActionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
        mouseActionBuilder.DragAndDropToOffset(source, xposOffset, yposOffset).Build().Perform();

    }
```

This code works in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but not Chrome.  Any ideas on why? Instead of dragging my sources, it is simply just doing nothing (visible that I can see, at least).

Comment: does this work `mouseActionBuilder .dragAndDrop(sourceElement,targetElement).Build().Perform();` ?

Comment: I don't think so. I tried that yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

***Seems like there are some issue with drag and drop in Webdriver.***

You could try changing the code :

```
WebElement sourceElement = <find an element from source location>;
WebElement targetElement = <find an element from target location>;
Actions mouseActionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
Actions dragAndDrop = mouseActionBuilder.clickAndHold(sourceElement).moveToElement(targetElement).release(targetElement);
dragAndDrop.Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Chrome is still doing nothing. It just not performing the click and drag. Bizarre that it is only Chrome failing here.

Comment: @DanPerlman : Indeed. Could you share more details over the question like driver initialisation, version of Chrome browser etc relevant to the scenario.

Comment: I believe all are up to date. Chrome driver 2.21 running Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m